# Multiple photos and text via ajax in php

Tags: php, ajax, image, upload

I edit multiple image upload scripts.
I added the features of uploading up to 3 photos and not uploading files larger than 5mb. It works successfully.
-- But I couldn't figure out how to define the text fields I added on js and how to send it to php document with post action.

Could you help?

I am posting the codes below.

php code:

```
<?php
    $dts = $_POST['dts'];
    $ttt = explode(',',$dts);
    $others_image_last='';
    $image_link="/upload_img/"; //folder name
     for($i=0; $i<sizeof($_FILES['upload_files']['name']); $i++) {
    if (in_array($i+1, $ttt)){}else{     
    $new_file = md5(microtime());
    $image_type = $_FILES["upload_files"]["type"][$i];
    $image_name = $_FILES["upload_files"]["name"][$i];
    $image_error = $_FILES["upload_files"]["error"][$i];
    $image_temp_name = $_FILES["upload_files"]["tmp_name"][$i];
    print_r($image_temp_name);
    if (($image_type == "image/jpeg") || ($image_type == "image/png") || ($image_type == "image/pjpeg") || ($image_type == "image/jpg")) {
        $test = explode('.', $image_name);
        $name = $new_file.'.'.end($test);
        $url = '.'.$image_link. $name;
        $info = getimagesize($image_temp_name);
        if ($info['mime'] == 'image/jpeg') $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($image_temp_name);
        elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/gif') $image = imagecreatefromgif($image_temp_name);
        elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/png') $image = imagecreatefrompng($image_temp_name);
        imagejpeg($image,$url,80);
    } 
    echo $name;
    /****** insert query here ******/
    }
    }?>
```

---

Html code

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html lang="en">
        <head>
           <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"/>
            <title>Multiple Photo Upload</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
    <style>
    .suggested-posts-article{
        background: white;
        -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.0666) 0 3px 10px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.0666) 0 3px 10px;
        box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.0666) 0 3px 10px;
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 5px;
        width: 23%;
    }
    article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, main, nav, section {
        display: block;
    }
    
    article, aside, footer, header, hgroup, main, nav, section {
        display: block;
    }
    
    .suggested-posts-articlees {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 49.5%;
    }
    @media screen and (max-width:450px) {
        .suggested-posts-article {
        
            width:40% !important;
            }
    }
    .more-photos:after{    right: 3px !important;
        bottom: 0px !important;}
        
    article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, main, nav, section {
        display: block;
    }
    .posts_article {
        background-color: #333;
        background-position: 50%;
        background-size: cover;
            margin-bottom: 2px;
        padding-bottom: 63.5%;
    }
    
    
    @media screen and (max-width:450px) {
        .suggested-posts-article {
        
            width:40% !important;
            }
    }
    
    .more-photos:after{    right: 3px !important;
        bottom: 0px !important;}
        
    .more-photos{
        cursor:pointer !important;
    }   
    
    .bluess {
        width:100%;
        margin:10px;
    }
    
    
    .btn-group-sm>.btn, .btn-sm {
        padding: .25rem .5rem;
        font-size: .875rem;
        line-height: 1.5;
        border-radius: .2rem;
    }
    
    .btn-outline-secondary {
        color: #868e96;
        background-color: transparent;
        background-image: none;
        border-color: #868e96;
    }
    
    
    .btnxc {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: .5rem .75rem;
        border:1px solid #868e96;
        margin:3px;
        padding: .25rem .5rem;
        font-size: .875rem;
        line-height: 1.5;
        border-radius: .2rem;
        color:#868e96;
    }
    .rrrr{
        color:red;
        fill:red;
    }
    .rrrr2{
        
        background-color:  red;
        
    }
     
    .datepost{
        margin-top:-15px;
    }
    .anther_ma
    {
        margin:1px;
    }
    
        
    
    .set_process
    {
        margin: 0px 7px 0px 0px;
    }
    .messaf{display:none;}
    .progress{
        width:80%;
    }
    .success_msg{
        color:green;
        display:none;
    }
    #post_send{
        margin:8px 0 8px 0;
    }
    .fa_p{
    margin-right:20px; 
    margin-top:10px; 
    border:0px; 
    z-index:9999
    }
    .p_run_div{
    margin-top:-7px;
    border-radius:0px; 
    padding:0px;
    margin-bottom:8px;
    display:none;
    }
    .btnxc{
    margin-left:15px;
    cursor:pointer;
    }
    .btnxc_r{
    margin-left:15px; 
    display:none;
    }
    
    </style>
    <div class="container">         
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <h2>Multiple Photo Upload</h2>
                <div class="form-group">
        <label for="examplename">Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="examplename" placeholder="First Name">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="examplesurname">First Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="examplesurname" placeholder="Last Name">
      </div>
                <div><button class="imgbuts btn btn-success" style='float:left'>Choose Photo...</button> <div id="uyari" style='float:left'>You can upload 3 photos.<br>
    Each photo should not be larger than 5 mb.</b></div></div>
                <div style="clear:both"></div>
                <form action="method" name="upload-file" class="main_form" id="form-upload-file" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div class="ui-block">
                        <aside class="suggested-posts">
                            <div class="suggested-posts-container"> 
                                <div class="row" id="message_box"></div> 
                            </div>  
                        </aside>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-md-2 " id='post_send' onclick="save_muliple_image()">Upload</button>
                <div class="progress">
                    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar"  style="width:0%">
                      <span class="sr-only">0</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <h2 class="success_msg">Photo upload completed.</h2>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div> 
    <script>
    var xp = 0;
    var input_btn = 0;
    var dts = [];
    $(document).on("click", ".imgbuts", function (e) {
    if(xp < 3){
      input_btn++;
      $("#form-upload-file").append(
        "<input type='file' style='display:none;' name='upload_files[]' id='filenumber" +
          input_btn +
          "' class='img_file upload_files' accept='.gif,.jpg,.jpeg,.png,' multiple/>"
      );
      $("#filenumber" + input_btn).click();
      } else {
      uyari.innerHTML = '&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; You can upload up to 3 photos.';
      }
    });
    
    $(document).on("change", ".upload_files", function (e){
      files = e.target.files;
      filesLength = files.length;
      for (var i = 0; i < filesLength; i++) {
          xp++; 
        var f = files[i];
        var boyut = f.size;
        var res_ext = files[i].name.split(".");
        var img_or_video = res_ext[res_ext.length - 1];
        var fileReader = new FileReader();
        var yuvarlama = (boyut / (1024*1024)).toFixed(2) + ' mb';
        uyari.innerHTML = '';
        if (boyut > 5000000) {uyari.innerHTML = '&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; File size larger than 5mb'; xp--; return;}
        fileReader.name = f.name;
          fileReader.onload = function (e) {
            var file = e.target;
            $("#message_box").append(
              "<article class='suggested-posts-article remove_artical" +
                xp +
                "' data-file='" +
                file.name +
                "'><div class='posts_article background_v" +
                xp +
                "' style='background-image: url(" +
                e.target.result +
                ")'></div><div class='p_run_div'><span class='pp_run progress_run" +
                xp +
                "' style='opacity: 1;'></span></div><p class='fa_p p_for_fa" +
                xp +
                "'><span class='cancel_mutile_image btnxc cancel_fa" +
                xp +
                "' deltsid='"+0+"'><b>&#10006; SİL</b></span><span class='btnxc btnxc_r' >&#10004;</span><span style='float:right'>"+ yuvarlama +"</span></p></article>"
            );
          };
          fileReader.readAsDataURL(f);
      }
      
    });
    
    
    function save_muliple_image() { 
    suggested = $(".suggested-posts-article").length;
      if (suggested > 0) {
        $(".cancel_mutile_image").prop("disabled", true);
        $("#post_send").prop("disabled", true);
        var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("form-upload-file"));
        formData.append("dts", dts); 
        var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
        $.ajax({
          url: 'upload_ajax.php',
          type: "POST",
          data: formData,
          processData: false,
          contentType: false,
          success: function (data) { 
            $(".main-content").find(".message-loading-overlay2").remove();
          },
          error: function (e) {
            $("#preview_file_div ul").html(
              "<li class='text-danger'>Something wrong! Please try again.</li>"
            );
          },
          xhr: function (e) {
            xhr.upload.addEventListener(
              "progress",
              function (e) {
                console.log(e);
                if (e.lengthComputable) {
                  var percentComplete = ((e.loaded || e.position) * 100) / e.total;
                  if(percentComplete==100){
                  $(".progress-bar").width(percentComplete + "%").html('99' + "%");
                  }else{ 
                  var yuzde = Math.floor(percentComplete);
                  $(".progress-bar").width(percentComplete + "%").html(yuzde + "%"); }
                }
              },
              false
            );
            xhr.addEventListener("load", function (e) {
              $('.progress-bar').css("background","#5cb85c").html('100' + "%");
              $(".btnxc_r").show();
              $(".success_msg").show();
              $(".cancel_mutile_image").remove();
            });
            return xhr;
          },
        });
      } else {
        $(".messaf").show();
      }
    }
    var rty=0;
    $(document).on("click", ".cancel_mutile_image", function (e) {
      $('.cancel_mutile_image').each(function(){ 
          chk_id = $(this).attr('deltsid');
          if(chk_id==0){ rty++; $(this).attr('deltsid',rty); }
      });
      deltsid = $(this).attr('deltsid');
      dts.push(deltsid);
      $(this).parents(".suggested-posts-article").remove();
      xp--;
    });
    </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Uploading multiple files in php  can be tricky but the trick you need to use here is that instead of using name="upload" in input filed use name="upload[]" it returns an array  so it makes the code much cleaner ... And to upload files use loops ( I used for loop in to see demonstrate how to upload different files here ) you can write some js and before uploading add some validations as per your needs !

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
  $path = "./"; // Specifiy the path where uploaded files goes 
  
  // Count # of uploaded files in array
  $total = count($_FILES['upload']['name']);
 
  // Loop through each file
  for ($i = 0; $i < $total; $i++) {

    //Get the temp file path
    $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'][$i];

    //Make sure we have a file path
    if ($tmpFilePath != "") {

      $target_path = $path;
      $target_path = $target_path.basename($_FILES['upload']['name'][$i]);
     
      // Upload files (YOUR IMAGES) into desired directory ! 
      
      if (move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $target_path)) {
        $success = "success";
      }
    }
  }
}

?>

<form action="index.php" method="POST" accept-charset="utf-8" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
  
<input type="file" name="upload[]" multiple />
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```